# Can we connect ActiveMQ Server running on PC with ActiveMQ Client running on android?

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, activemq-classic

I am trying to send a message to ActiveMQ from a sender written in C# and then trying to receive the message on an android device running ActiveMQ Client.

I was not able to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using the paho eclipse client.

Here is my code:

```
    //Connection with the server
    private void connect() {
        MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);

        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this, serverURI, clientId);
        try {
            client.connect(connectOptions, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    publishBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    subscribe();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, ActiveMQ MQTT Server on pc(local IP )  can be connected to android device using paho . Few important things to consider are , #paho Service be added and declared in manifest, the service should be started on the pc,  the ip used for connecting should be your local ip of the pc and some config files needs to be changed for the activeMQ server.

Comment: @Kaveri any refrence with example will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this as long as you have configured the broker to add an MQTT Transport endpoint.  You will also need to ensure your device can reach the broker which could be behind a firewall or other security measures so configuration here is key.  The ActiveMQ 5.x broker configuration for MQTT is documented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html).